# FireFox Security Warning using Pay Pal v0.51

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using the  `PHP Toolkit for PayPal v0.51`

I have setup Pay Pal sandbox accounts and done a test to the ipn.php that comes back as working ok.

I have set the config.inc.php to suit my settings

`PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze15` `mysql` and `cURL` installed all is working fine.

**When using with IE**
everything works fine, the transaction is returned to the `success.php` and in the `ipn_success.php` 
I have it updating the database with the information posted back from Pay Pal.

**When using Firefox**
Everything works fine till I get to the part where it returns me back to the success.php
I get a Security Warning box open up with the below information within it.

> Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?

If I click the warning straight away I get the information posted back and the database is updated.

If I leave this warning for a few seconds, I lose all the information that is posted back to the site for the database.

How can I stop this security warning from showing when using Firefox

The website is using http and not using https so Pay Pay is posting back to a non ssl site.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a known issue with FireFox that we are currently looking into.  If you would like to be notified once the issue is resolved, you can open up a ticket with [PayPal's Merchant Technical Support](http://www.paypal.com/mts).  PPXO-7400

Comment: Hi PP_MTS_Chad Thank you for the fast reply I will open ticket.

Comment: April 2013 and STILL this problem is present!!! Crazy. You would have thought PayPal would have fixed this after 9 months!!